# Multiple requests from a single ip address (MySQL & apache)

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, load-balancing

Are there any queuing issues/limits that I should be aware of when running a web application on a remote server with all of it's users are going to be making requests from the same IP address?

The application will be running on a manage dedicated server which is running Redhat with MySQL 5 and apache2.

Comment: As in all of the users are behind a NAT? Or all the users are connecting through a bastion/proxy host?

Comment: Behind a NAT, with the remote server being a bog standard public Apache setup

Comment: I don't have any specific experience to speak of but I don't think you setup would introduce any special limitations. I'd guess your server will hit unusable load before you run out of available NAT ports.

Comment: Recall that separate applications run on separate ports, you should be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Remember that with NAT, all requests even though they will be from the SAME IP, will be from different source ports. This would be seen no different than an increase of traffic from different IP's.